# Loop break in Shell script - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script where I need to run one query in loop until `count` in one of the `hive` table is equal to 0.

In resource.hsql file, I am moving data from temp table to resource table based on condition and at each run `count` is decreasing in temp table.

Initial `count` in temp table is 5.

Below is the script that I am running and it is giving me echo `count=5` every time and loop is not breaking even after we have 0 count in temp table.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(hive -e "select count(*) from temp;");

while [ "$count" != 0 ]
do
    echo "Count>>>>>>> $count"
    hive -f resource.hsql
    if [ "$count" -eq  0 ]
    then break
    fi
done
```

Please suggest the workaround for this.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You only ever set `count` once. It will never change its value. If you want to query again, you have to run `count=$(hive -e "select count(*) from temp;");` again inside the loop

Comment: Reduce the count like: `count=$((count - 1))`

Comment: I need the count value from temp table. based on that I need to run query in loop until count>0

Comment: Your first line assigns a value, but you treat it as if it were a function that's evaluated every time you call `$count`. You could make it into a function instead: `count() { hive -e 'select count(*) from temp;'; }` and then check `if [ "$(count)" -neq 0 ]` and `if [ "$(count)" -eq 0 ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the command repeatedly. Your code would only run it once.

```
while
    count="$(hive -e "select count(*) from temp;")"
    [ "$count" != 0 ]
do
    echo "Count>>>>>>> $count"
    hive -f resource.hsql
done
```

Notice also how the `while` condition already controls the loop, so there is no need to separately `break` on the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

***Simply:***

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(hive -e "select count(*) from temp;");

while [ "$count" != 0 ]
do
    echo "Count>>>>>>> $count"
    hive -f resource.hsql
    count=$((count - 1))
done
```

**Advice:**

> You don't need this

```
if [ "$count" -eq  0 ]
then break
fi
```

> while loop breaks once count is 0